# How to make a Widget clickable?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button, clickable

So I have this code that displays a card expanded with a gif and a tittle and so I want to make this ‪clickable for me to when I click it takes me to the specify thing page. So what I want to do is, this results on a screen with some gifs and for each gif it has a name, i want the cardView gifs to be clickable.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vertical_card_pager/vertical_card_pager.dart';
import 'models/hero_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //List for agents and respective gif for each one.
  final List<HeroModel> heros = [
    HeroModel("JETT", "images/jett_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("KILLJOY", "images/killjoy_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SAGE", "images/sage_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SOVA", "images/sova_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("VIPER", "images/viper_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("RAZE", "images/raze_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("YORU", "images/yoru_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("BREACH", "images/breach_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("ASTRA", "images/astra_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("CYPHER", "images/cypher_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("OMEN", "images/omen_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("PHOENIX", "images/phoenix_valo.gif"),
    HeroModel("SKYE", "images/skye_valo.gif"),
  ];

  @override
  //Head Logo
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 70,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            child: Center(
              child: Image.asset(
                "images/logo.png",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // CardView
        Expanded(
            child: VerticalCardPager(
          titles: [for (var hero in heros) hero.title],
          images: [
            for (var hero in heros)
              Hero(
                tag: hero.title,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    hero.image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
          textStyle:
              const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          initialPage: 2,
          align: ALIGN.CENTER,
        ))
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

Comment: i would prefer using GestureDetector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap widget with **GestureDetector** write code click in onTap

```
GestureDetector(onTap: (){},child:Expanded(
            child: VerticalCardPager(
          titles: [for (var hero in heros) hero.title],
          images: [
            for (var hero in heros)
              Hero(
                tag: hero.title,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    hero.image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
          textStyle:
              const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          initialPage: 2,
          align: ALIGN.CENTER,
        ))),
```

Comment: it return me this error message ` FlutterError (BoxConstraints has NaN values in minHeight and maxHeight. The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, NaN<=h<=NaN; NOT NORMALIZED))`

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your widget with `Inkwell` and use `onTap` callback.

In column you can't able to use `Expanded` and `Sizedbox` as it's children. Try removing the `Expanded`.

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    // TODO: add your function callback here
  },
  child: VerticalCardPager(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      initialPage: 2,
      align: ALIGN.CENTER,
      titles: [for (var hero in heros) hero.title],
      images: [
        for (var hero in heros)
          Hero(
            tag: hero.title,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                hero.image,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    ),
)
```

Comment: I tried it before and i got this error message **FlutterError (BoxConstraints has NaN values in minHeight and maxHeight. The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, NaN<=h<=NaN; NOT NORMALIZED))**

Comment: Share you complete widget tree

Answer (score 1):

You can use Listview.builder for Listing and Then You can manage and tap on Particular Item.

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(itemCount:heros.length,itemBuilder:(context,index){
              return VerticalCardPager(
          titles: hero[index].title,
          images: 
          
              Hero(
                tag: hero[index].title.title,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    hero[index].title.image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            textStyle:
              const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          initialPage: 2,
          align: ALIGN.CENTER,
        )
            })
        )
```

Comment: okay it may work but it still gives me this error: FlutterError (BoxConstraints has NaN values in minHeight and maxHeight.
The offending constraints were:
  BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, NaN<=h<=NaN; NOT NORMALIZED))

Comment: Can you please try to Remove expanded widget and run it?